# Which file of VS code I should use as Unity3D External Script Editor?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, archlinux

My VS code doesn't want to autocomplete UnityEngine keywords. I read that I need to set VS as external script editor, but which file of it I should use as ESE? I'm using Manjaro and VS code installed with **snap**, UnityEditor installed with UnityHub.

Answer (score 0):

You need code completion for Unity installed in VSCode. At the moment you have told Unity you want to use VSCode, but you haven't told VSCode that you are working with Unity's API.

Check out the "Enabling code completion" section on this page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

Comment: Hello, Joseph! You didn't understand me. In your guide they're selecting Code as ESE and there are no field like External Script Editor Args, but I have it. I think that happens because I selected wrong VS file